# Remote restore gz mysql database

Tags: ssh, mysql, remote, restore, gz

I tried

```
$> ssh root@ip "gunzip < [backupfile.sql.gz] | \
      mysql -u [uname] -p[pass] [dbname]"`
```

but get the error:

```
ERROR 1044 (42000) at line 42: Access denied for user '[uname]'@'%'
                               to database '[dbname]'
```

I could do

```
$> ssh root@ip "mysql -u [uname] -p[pass] [dbname] -e 'drop table [table]'"
```

So I guess it can't be a remote permission problem.

What is the correct command to do a remote restore of gz file to mysql via ssh then?

Answer (score 0):

The user you are using does not have the file privilege to read file on the server. Just grant file privilege to the user and you will be fine.